# How do I suppress keypress being printed to console in .NET?

Tags: c#, .net, console

I'm porting a small C++ console game to C# and it seems that I can't stop key presses from being printed to the console.

In C++ I get the keystroke with this method, which also suppress the keystrokes from being printed to the console:

```
bool Game::getInput(char *c)
{
    if (_kbhit())
    {
        *c = _getch();
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

I tried to do the equivalent in C# by doing:

```
Key = Console.ReadKey();
```

But this does not suppress the character from being printed to the console, causing obvious problems. Any ideas on how to remedy this?

Comment: Having trouble reproducing the bug I describe? Check if you can read a line and use arrow keys to edit the line as a standard library function. If you can't do that; get that working and watch the bug I described reappear.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

You want [`Console.ReadKey(true)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x3h8xffw.aspx)

> Obtains the next character or function key pressed by the user. The pressed key is optionally displayed in the console window.

The argument - which is called *intercept*:

> Determines whether to display the pressed key in the console window. **true** to not display the pressed key; otherwise, **false**.

Answer (score 6):

The `ReadKey` method has an [overload that takes a bool](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x3h8xffw.aspx) as a parameter. Pass in `true` and it will not display the input in the console.

Comment: 1) Calling ReadKey() in a loop never worked for reasons that should be obvious. 2) ReadKey(bool) has been withdrawn.

Comment: @Joshua Not sure what you mean by "withdrawn" - it's still [there in .Net 8](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.console.readkey?view=net-8.0&redirectedfrom=MSDN#system-console-readkey(system-boolean)).

Comment: A misread on the .NET 8 release notes.

Answer (score 1):

It should be possible to handle full line reading with keys suppression by taking advantage of [ReadKey(bool intercept)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.console.readkey?view=net-8.0#system-console-readkey(system-boolean)) with some custom solution like:

```
public static string? ReadLine(bool intercept)
{
    if (!intercept)
    {
        return Console.ReadLine();
    }

    StringBuilder sb = new();
    int position = 0;
    ConsoleKeyInfo c;
    do
    {
        c = Console.ReadKey(true);
        if (!char.IsControl(c.KeyChar))
        {
            sb.Insert(position++, c.KeyChar);
        }
        else
        {
            switch (c.Key)
            {
                case ConsoleKey.Delete:
                    if (position < sb.Length)
                        sb.Remove(position, 1);

                    break;
                case ConsoleKey.Backspace:
                    if (position > 0)
                        sb.Remove(--position, 1);

                    break;
                case ConsoleKey.LeftArrow:
                    position = Math.Max(position - 1, 0);
                    break;
                case ConsoleKey.RightArrow:
                    position = Math.Min(position + 1, sb.Length);
                    break;
                case ConsoleKey.End:
                    position = sb.Length;
                    break;
                case ConsoleKey.Home:
                    position = 0;
                    break;
                default:
                    if (c.KeyChar == 26) // Ctrl+Z
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(); // End of input. Move to next line
                        return null;
                    }
                    break;
            }
        }
    } while (c.Key != ConsoleKey.Enter);

    Console.WriteLine(); // End of input. Move to next line
    return sb.ToString();
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Console.Write("Insert something: ");
    var input = ReadLine(true);
    Console.WriteLine($"You typed: {input}");
}
```

Comment: That's the best answer I've seen so far. I still have to p/invoke to find out what the kill line and delete keys actually are but that does in fact reduce the problem.

Comment: @Joshua Sorry, I don't think that I fully understand what you mean with "what the kill line and delete keys actually are"

Comment: Backspace key: delete left of cursor. Delete key: delete right of cursor: kill key: entire line. The problem is they move around. Technically the backspace does too, but that hasn't needed to be changed in ages. Run `stty -all` to see the current assignments. The thing about kill key is it's very nice for entering passwords because it's easy to know you typo'd it but not know exactly where.

Comment: @Joshua So the point is that for example `case ConsoleKey.Delete` may be wrong if the user has another Delete key configured? In this case it may be useful to check on `c.KeyChar` (ex: `c.KeyChar == 0` -> user pressed Delete key. `c.KeyChar == 8` -> user pressed backspace. And so on...)

Comment: `(c.KeyChar == 0)` -> delete is definitely wrong though. I haven't taken apart `ConsoleKeyInfo.Key` to see if it actually works yet; however Kill isn't in the enum.