# Change string (font) mode to password mode in c#

Tags: c#, console-application, windows

I am currently working on console application.

I got an issue for login functionality in a console application .

If the user enters the username and password, then clicks the enter button, it will check other logic.

Now I want to the change the password(string)ordinary mode to password mode for anyone don't see the user input password .

Here is my code

```
Console.Write("Please enter the Password: ");
string password = Console.ReadLine();
```

> I want to change the string (password) text mode to password, whenever the user type the password in console window.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3404421/password-masking-console-application

Comment: @Habib , If the User type 10000 characters, All time the foreach rounding  ?

Comment: `ReadLine` doesn't take any argument, look at the linked question how input should be taken

Comment: Sorry , I changed that !!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Basically it comes down to a loop with `Console.ReadKey(true)` until the user presses <kbd>Enter</kbd>. Passing true for the `intercept` parameter to [ReadKey](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x3h8xffw.aspx) will keep the pressed key from being displayed.

Check out the following post: [How do I suppress keypress being printed to console in .NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2484290/how-do-i-supress-keypress-being-printed-to-console-in-net).

It allows you to read one character without displaying it in console. You then need to implement your own logic for storing the characters until enter is pressed.

Comment: Have you tried it? Occasionally outputs a couple characters from password.